# Why no visual feedback when uninstalling Visual Studio 2010 Beta 1

Tags: uninstall

I am attempting to un-install Visual Studio 2010 Beta 1 from a Windows 7 RC machine.

- Selected: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional Beta 1 - ENU
- Clicked "Uninstall/Change"
- No visual feedback.
- Clicking the "Uninstall/Change" again does nothing for a while then returns with a message indicating the windows installer is busy with another process.
- Task manager indicates that "Msiexec.exe" CPU usage (0% -> 50%)

Why is there no visual feedback? Is this by design?

Answer (score 1):

It's Beta?  Check the MSDN site for updates and possible issues.  How long have you waited?

Comment: Been waiting for 1 hour.

Comment: Cannot kill the process either.  It keeps restarting.

Comment: I had no such problems. The uninstall finished quite fast.

Answer (score -1):

You may just need to wait, and keep it running until it finishes.

Depending on how deeply entrenched it is on your machine, you may need to leave it to run its course. It took my machine (which is admittedly pretty slow) four attempts, each of over an hour, and in the end a straight three hour process and was finally cleared.